# What is correct (possessive question)

Tags: possessives

I haven't the foggiest how to express this basic idea correctly in English:

The meaning is "the trip that Paul and I will make to London". So, is "Paul and I's trip to London" or "Paul and mine trip to London" or "Paul and my trip to London".

Thanks chaps. PS I'm a native speaker!

Answer (score 1):

The Chicago Manual of Style says that when talking about something owned by, or associated with, another person and oneself, it is "polite" as well as grammatical to put oneself last:

> Paul's and my trip to London.

[Pronouns](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Pronouns/faq0005.html)

Comment: I found Michael Harvey's answer downvoted and I upvoted it as correct - if somewhat brief. The difference between the first and second answers appears to hinge upon whether the two nouns concerned share possession of an object - as explained in Englishmonger's link. This question might well be open to interpretation.

Answer (score -1):

When  Multiple  nouns  have  single  ownership  the  possessive  form  is  applicable  to  the  second  noun.

David  and John's  adventures  are  hilarious.

In the  sentence  choosen  by  the  OP, 
 one  is  a  noun  and  the  other is  pronoun  in a  possessive  case.

We  can not  say  paul  and  mine  adventures.

So  the  correct  option  seems  to be:

> **Paul  and  my  trip  to  London**

Here we  can not  say  Paul   trip to  London  or  My trip to London.. They  are  going  together. So  it  is  correct say  Paul  and  my  trip rather  than   Paul's  and  my trip  to  London.
We  can  not  say  Jack's and  jill's adventures.

Here  is  a  link  which  explains the  rules:

https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/possessive-nouns.html

Comment: Paul and my trip? Really? Would you say "Paul trip to London"?

Comment: @ Michael Harvey. If  there  are  two  nouns, the  possessive  is  applicable  to  the  last.Please  see the  link.Different  links say differently. Can we  say  jack  adventures? Jack  and  Jill's  adventured